# How to QA test Azure Analysis Service created by dev team

Tags: azure, azure-analysis-services

Our development team want me to create functional test cases for Azure Analysis service. How do i test them and test cases should cover to ensure AAS is tested success.

I have no background and thoughts on where to start

Finally manual functional test cases are to be created.

Comment: What exactly do you want to test?